# React - opening a link in the same tab and click on a button in the new link

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to search for a similar problem but I couldn't find one.
here is my problem -
In my React app - I have a button that after pressing on it, it should open a new URL (in the same tab) - so far so good.
I know that in the new URL there is a button with an identifier.
How can I open the window and after the DOM is loaded - press the button?
when I tried to use querySelect to get the button I received null but I believe it's because that the DOM was not fully loaded.

here is the onClick function:

```
function func(){
    newPath = '***SOME URL****';
    newWindow = window.open(newPath , "_self");
    newWindow.document
            .querySelector("*** SOME IDENTIFIER ***")
            .click();
}
```

Is it possible? if so, what is the best approach to handle this case?
Thanks.

Comment: And what's the goal of clicking thuis button , do you have an event to be excucted ? if yes , just fire this event

Comment: how about `newWindow.document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ...)` ?

Comment: Thanks for the comments.
Using "DOMContentLoaded" has no effect - it seems like the event was fired before it gets to the addEventListener.
In addition, when I tried to inspect the document object of the new window it returns content that belongs to the previous URL.

Comment: if the source of '***SOME URL****' is react too, you could call click() event in didMount or useEffecte when open url and did mounted element the click event fire.

Comment: @OA617 : or may you could use document.addEventListener('readystatechange', (event) => {
   // add addEventListener with event
});

Answer (score 0):

See the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/36096571/8672333.

You can do something like:

```
function func(){
    newPath = '***SOME URL****';
    newWindow = window.open(newPath , "_self");

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
       // Your DOM should be fully loaded here
       newWindow.document
            .querySelector("*** SOME IDENTIFIER ***")
            .click();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Using "DOMContentLoaded" has no effect - it seems like the event was fired before it gets to the addEventListener.
In addition, when I tried to inspect the document object of the new window it returns content that belongs to the previous URL.